# Redis connection best practices for use with an Azure Consumption Function

Tags: redis, azure-functions

Redis best practices recommendeds using a long-lived ConnectionMultiplexer. However I want to use Redis inside an azure consumption function that may only live a couple of seconds (but runs many times).

I was wondering if I had code like this:

```
        private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyRedisConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
    {
        string cacheConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisKey"].ToString();
        return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(cacheConnection);
    });

    public static ConnectionMultiplexer RedisConnection
    {
        get
        {
            return lazyRedisConnection.Value;
        }
    }
```

On an Azure Consumption function, that runs e.g. 10000 times. Because of the way Azure Consumption functions work, this would actually create 10000 connections rather then reuse a single one?

Would it be safer to manually create/dispose a connection per function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though a single function execution might only take a couple seconds, the function *instance* (server) is being reused for multiple requests. In practice, with a constant stream of incoming requests, each instance lives long (minutes to hours).

Database Connections should be reused between the calls that are executed on the same instance.

Static fields are initialized once and then get reused for multiple executions, so your code will not create 10000 connections, but maybe 1 or 2 or 3 depending on how many instances will be created by the scale controller.

When an instance goes down, your App Domain will be recycled, so the connections to Redis will be killed.

I would suggest you go ahead with the code you quoted.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know if it could cause an issue over the long term? Azure limit is 256 clients, so a slow build up would still cause issues if a client never disconnects. The Redis timeout server config is locked down on Azure and I can't get/set it's value.

Comment: @RedRidingHood Won't it disconnect when instance is torn down and `ConnectionMultiplexer` is disposed?

Comment: That is the essence of my question, because it is a disposable, but I would not be disposing it myself because I don't know when the instance is torn down. I'm not sure if it will disconnect, or if the redis clients connected count will stay the same.

Comment: @RedRidingHood Yes, it will disconnect. AFAIK `ConnectionMultiplexer` is encouraged to be made static in any application, so it will be released once the application ends execution. Same applies to Function instance, I've extended the answer a bit.

Comment: After reading https://mcguirev10.com/2018/02/05/cache-release-resources-azure-functions.html I implemented an event to dispose the redis connection when the service is torn down.

Comment: @MikhailShilkov, On reusing the same redis connection object across multiple requests, wont it results in piling up the requests & eventually slows down the app performance?